# Is there a cleaner way to write this? (digit to string)

Tags: c++

I made a number to digit converter, but it seems too verbose the way it is written.
I seem some people talking about using a switch. Should I rewrite this with a switch or is there a better way to write it?

```
string numberToString(int n)
{
  if (n == 0)
    return "zero";
  if (n == 1)
    return "one";
  if (n == 2)
    return "two";
  if (n == 3)
    return "three";
  if (n == 4)
    return "four";
  if (n == 5)
    return "five";
  if (n == 6)
    return "six";
  if (n == 7)
    return "seven";
  if (n == 8)
    return "eight";
  if (n == 9)
    return "nine";
  else
    return "?";
}
```

Comment: A switch would be equally verbose. You could use an array.

Comment: Use a [map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using an array literal.

```
string numberToString(int n) {
  return (n >= 0 && n <= 9) ?
    (string[]){
      "zero",
      "one",
      "two",
      "three",
      "four",
      "five",
      "six",
      "seven",
      "eight",
      "nine",
    }[n]
  :
    "?";
}
```

Comment: For some reason this is failing to compile for me with VS2017 CE set the C++ latest draft standard...

Comment: Compiles with g++ 5.4  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: while this looks elegant, it will in fact construct 10 redundant strings on every call.

Comment: @RichardHodges **good point.** I just whipped it up fast to show how one _could_ use an array and an index to avoid an if/else chain or a switch.

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't use a switch at all

```
std::string numberToString(int n) 
{
    const char *literal[] = {"zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five",
                           "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"};
    const char *no_result = "?";

    return std::string ( (n < 0 || n >= 10) ? no_result : literal[n]); 
}
```

The conversion in the return statement is optional (it happens implicitly) but I prefer to make it explicit.

The types of `literal` and `no_result` can be made to `std::string` if desired.

Comment: This looks slow. Both literal and no_result are allocated and initialized on the stack each time the function is called.

Comment: @JohannesOvermann - that's not true.   String literals have static storage duration, and even primitive compilers will probably avoid creating the variables each time.  That's an elementary transformation for a compiler.   If it's really a concern, make the variables `static`.   Worrying about and tweaking code like this for performance, is called "premature optimisation" for a reason - unless there is evidence (from profiling) of a performance concern, there are better things to expend effort on.

Comment: @P: You are giving the answer to a new contributor who will easily fall into the pitfall to create complex objects on the stack. Yes, these variables should be static. Explicit is better than implicit. And yes, performance is a primary concern, otherwise there would be little reason to use C++, a language in which each and every feature is designed to yield maximum runtime performance, even at the cost of convenience, stability and security.

Comment: @JohannesOvermann - That comment is a bit rich, since your answer uses exactly the same logic, but in a single statement.   That statement creates an array of `std::string`  (which is a more complicated structure than an array of `char *`) on the stack as a temporary.    If you are so worried about performance, change your answer so it doesn't have the same flaws that you are accusing me of introducing.

Answer (score 1):

Short version:

```
std::string numberToString(int n)
{
    return (const char *[]){"zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five",
            "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "?"}[unsigned(n) < 11 ? n : 10];
}
```

Answer (score -3):

This would easily work and is very readable and reusable.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class Converter {
private:
    const std::vector<std::string> numbers{ "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four",
                                            "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "?" };
public:
    std::string operator()( int n ) { 
        if ((n < 0) || (n > 10))
             return numbers.at(10);   
       return numbers.at(n); 
    }
};


int main() {
     Converter c;
     for ( int i = -5; i < 15; i++ )
         std::cout << c(5) << '\n';

     return 0;
}
```

*-Output-*

```
?
?
?
?
?
zero
one
two
three
four
five
six
seven
eight
nine
?
?
?
?
?
?
```

Comment: This throws an exception if `n` is outside 0-9, which differs from what the OP requested.   Suggest fixing.

Comment: @Peter I was just giving the basic structure; and of course this would throw an exception due to vector's at function.

Comment: @Peter It shouldn't of been that hard of a fix for the OP to figure out, but I've updated the code with a possible fix.

Comment: @Peter I had a typo in the return it is fixed now

Comment: I didn't down-vote, but your solution looks unnecessarily more complicated than needed (that's why I didn't up-vote - other folks may be more aggressive).

Comment: How is it that complicated... You have a constant vector of strings that is known at compile time. You have an `operator()` to that class functor that takes an integer value. Depending on the value passed in, it will return the appropriate index giving you the string you want.

Comment: This solution is way to complex for the task. Not a good example of how to use C++, but a good example of how C++ is used in many places. Simplicity is bliss. Don't create a class for something which is a function. Using a vector here is really unnecessary and costly.

Comment: @JohannesOvermann If vector is too costly then one can easily substitute it with array....

Comment: @Francis: Yes, exactly. And one can omit the class. And the private access control. And creating an instance on the stack just to do the conversion. And several memory bytes. And several CPU cycles.