# typecasted c++ pointer and non-typecasted pointer points to same location,but gives different values

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, typecasting-operator

In the following code

```
#include <string.h> 
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 

int main() 
{ 
    int *a;
    const int b=5;
    a=(int *)&b;
    *a=6;
    cout<<*a<<b<<endl;
    cout<<a<<" "<<&b;

    return 0; 
}
```

address of `b` is typecasted and stored into `a`.So to my knowledge `*a` must be pointing to same location as `b` and should give  same value as b.Getting an output of a and &b shows that both of them points to the same memory location.
But the a* and b gives different values as outputs.If i have not typecasted the pointer then i would have got same value for *a and b.Can someone help my find whats wrong here?.Thanks in Advance

```
65
0x7fff2e7969fc 0x7fff2e7969fc
```

Comment: What you have there is undefined behaviour.

Comment: When you change a value declared as const your program has undefined behaviour. You are lucky it didn't crash.

Comment: @john Actually, he would have been luckier if it did crash.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to write on a variable (`b`) which was declared `const`. This is `undefined behavior` in C++. Undefined behavior means, that the program may do *anything* at this point, everything is valid, including printing completely wrong numbers or even crashing.

You first promised that `b` is constant and they you broke this promise.

The compiler gave you a hint that what you do is not allowed, by forcing you to insert a cast. Without the `(int*)` cast your code will not compile, because it is not const correct. Casting around `const` is often a hint that something is not correct. There are legitimate uses for casting around `const`, but not in situations like your code where the underlying variable is really `const`.

The cases where you are allowed to cast around `const` all involve a non-const variable, and having a const pointer to it, and then casting the `const` pointer to a non-const one, for example since you still maintain logical constness, e.g. you maintain an important invariant. But the underlying storage is always non-const in these scenarios.

This is most likely what happens in your scenario:

The compiler remembers that you want to give the value 5 the name `b`. It also realizes that you are taking a pointer to `b`, so in addition it reserves space for `b` on the stack. It will most likely not even bother to put the 5 onto the stack until you try to read it, but you never do. Instead you overwrite the location for `b` on the stack with 6. So the print statements first print a 6 (for the location of b on the stack) and then a 5 (the compiler simply inserts a 5 everywhere where you use `b`).

Comment: [Your answer to my unrelated question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54845646/1275653) remains the sole answer. I would like to leave my question open for now, *accepting* no answer, but do not wish to deny you reputation points. Instead, I have reviewed some of your other answers to find two good ones I can upvote. This is one. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54728765/1275653) is the other. Both are good answers, both deservedly +1. So, no *acceptance,* but you and I should be even on the points.

Comment: @thb: That is not necessary, but this is very kind of you! Thanks! :-)